# How Can I change paragraph when select other option?

Tags: javascript

```
      <p class="price">$14</p>
      <select name="price">
        <option class="opt">Monthly</option>
        <option class="opt">6 Months</option>
        <option class="opt">Yearly</option>
      </select>
```

change price :
which event should I use

Comment: The [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a good time

Display one of the select items by default
Then it changes when the user selects either

```js
const selectPrice = document.querySelector('#selectPrice');
const outputPrice = document.querySelector('.price');

selectPrice.addEventListener("change" , (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
  outputPrice.innerText = e.target.value;
})
```

```html
   <p class="price">Monthly</p>
      <select name="price" id="selectPrice">
        <option class="opt">Monthly</option>
        <option class="opt">6 Months</option>
        <option class="opt">Yearly</option>
      </select>
```

I hope I could help